# AWS S3 Bucket returning 403 forbiden

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, heroku, amazon-s3, static

I have an application in Django and I put it my static files in a bucket on AWS S3. However, when I try to connect in my application the bucket S3 return 403 forbidden for static files.

My bucket has a public access configurated for it.

[image]

If I try to access the file directly an XML error is returned like:

**This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.**

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>2A64DBA5BD88AC1C</RequestId>
<HostId>
K7NHlv7xhPAL6626LCHLayoR4BauqARf6KaTtKUYKQsakNqQ1LL6RnuIwxUqjMP0q6UjMmiW7Yw=
</HostId>
</Error>
```

My bucket has the files:

[image]
[image]

I tried to change settings putting AWS_DEFAULT_ACL like 'public', 'private' and None, but the problem persists...

Obs.: My app is in Heroku.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 5):

Public access requires quite a few things.  Have you done all the following?

Bucket > Permissions > Block public access button > Block all public access set to off.

Bucket > Bucket Policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKETNAME/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

This last one is only for static website hosting.  As you mentioned, you're not serving .html files because you're building a Django app.  Still, I'm leaving it here in case someone finds it useful.

Bucket > Properties > Static Website Hosting > Use this bucket to host a website.

Comment: The policy and permission yes, I did. But website hosting not because I do not have file home.html or index.html inde bucket, only static files.

Comment: Whoops! You're right, that last one would be completely unnecessary.  Glad you got it figured out!

Answer (score 0):

To solve this case, I needed to click with the right button and turn public all directory static.

[image]